# Apply Same CSS to multiple ID's using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need an html structure that looks like this:

```
<div id="ABTestBanner_New">
</div>

<div id="ABTestBanner_Fav">
</div>

<div id="ABTestBanner_Budget">
</div>
```

I need to use it in an AB split test. So I need to write in javaScript, and I need all three divs to be unique id's but have the same CSS.  I tried to do it this way but only the #ABTestBanner_Budget is getting the CSS applied:

```
var $divNew = $('<div></div>', {'id': 'ABTestBanner_New'});
$('div.samplesCell.samples1').after($divNew)

var $divFav = $('<div></div>', {'id': 'ABTestBanner_Fav'});
$($divNew).after($divFav);

var $divBudget = $('<div></div>', {'id': 'ABTestBanner_Budget'});
$($divFav).after($divBudget);

$('#ABTestBanner_New' && '#ABTestBanner_Fav' && '#ABTestBanner_Budget').css({
    float : 'left',
    height : '250px',
    width : '950px',
    backgroundColor:'#0080FF',
    margin:'20px 0px 20px 0px'
});
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Seperate them with commas.

Comment: basic javascript: `'a' && 'b' && 'c'` is not doing what you think it's doing...

Comment: You might as well have written the following: $(true).css({ blah, blah }); ... just set a bookmark for the API documentation (seen in my previous comment). Any valid string will evaluation to `true` ... especially when evaluating a function argument with ampersands performing boolean logic.

Comment: Use a class?  Your CSS is not dynamic in any way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See jquery docs here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$('#ABTestBanner_New, #ABTestBanner_Fav, #ABTestBanner_Budget').css({
    /*your style*/
});
```

Comment: You should NOT have even typed that out. I added the link to the docs (as a comment to the original question). People should not be asking questions like this expecting to be "spoon fed". Devs have spent a lot of time developing good documentation -- we need to point people to the APIs. If they're confused by what they read there -- that's different. But, they should at least look at the documentation first.

Comment: @JoeJohnson, Thank for feedback, I'm duplicate your link to API in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Simply** use:

```
$('div[id^="ABTestBanner"]').css({
    /* styles */
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rw53Q/

The `div[id^="ABTestBanner"]` selector targets all `div` elements whose `id` start with `ABTestBanner`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add a class to those elements and style the class the way you want to?

```
$ABTestBanner_New.addClass("foo");
$ABTestBanner_Fav.addClass("foo");
$ABTestBanner_Budget.addClass("foo");
```

Adding/Removing a class is a little more efficient than adding inline styles on the fly, it also helps to keep all your styles in the CSS file where they belong. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ABTestBanner_New , #ABTestBanner_Fav , #ABTestBanner_Budget').css({
    float : 'left',
    height : '250px',
    width : '950px',
    backgroundColor:'#0080FF',
    margin:'20px 0px 20px 0px'
});
```

instead of && use comma